# JavaScript - 1. .splice() acts weird 2. .classList.add acts weird

Tags: javascript

I'm making To Do List app using vanilla JavaScript. Currently I have two problems.

1. When I delete items from the bottom of the list, delete function works fine. However if I delete from the top, it first deletes the item from the bottom, then the second one, and lastly the top one. How do I fix this so that I can delete the one that I exactly clicked?
2. If I click Check button, the task should be marked as done, and 'completed' class will be added to html. However if I click Check button, in data structure it seems the value of 'isCompleted' is successfully toggled but class will be removed from html right away, like after 0.01 seconds.

What are the problems and how do I fix them?

```
const todoBlock = document.querySelector(".task__nav");
const submitForm = document.querySelector(".form");
const taskItem = document.querySelector(".task");

const taskContainer = document.querySelector(".todo__container");

const showAllTasksNav = document.querySelector(".task__nav-item.all");
const showCompletedTasksNav = document.querySelector(
  ".task__nav-item.finished"
);

const taskContainer_new = document.querySelector(".items");

let todoList = [];
todoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todolist")) || [];
updateUI();

submitForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (taskItem.value !== "") {
    addTodo(taskItem.value);
  }
});

function addTodo(task) {
  const todo = {
    task: taskItem.value,
    isCompleted: false,
    id: Date.now()
  };

  todoList.push(todo);

  updateUI();
  clearInput();
}

function updateUI() {
  taskContainer_new.textContent = "";

  todoList.forEach(el => {
    showItems(el.id, el.task);
  });
  localStorage.setItem("todolist", JSON.stringify(todoList));
}

function showItems(id, task) {
  const markup = `
  <div class="todo__item" data-key=${id}>
  <p>${task}</p>
  <div class="icons">
  <button class="item__complete--btn"><svg class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="1em" height="1em" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M340.1 177.3L215.3 303l-47.2-47.2-17.8 17.8 56 56c2.5 2.5 5.9 4.5 8.9 4.5s6.3-2 8.8-4.4l133.7-134.4-17.6-18z" fill="#626262"/><path d="M256 48C141.1 48 48 141.1 48 256s93.1 208 208 208 208-93.1 208-208S370.9 48 256 48zm0 398.7c-105.1 0-190.7-85.5-190.7-190.7 0-105.1 85.5-190.7 190.7-190.7 105.1 0 190.7 85.5 190.7 190.7 0 105.1-85.6 190.7-190.7 190.7z" fill="#626262"/></svg></button>
  <button class="item__delete--btn"><svg class="ion-ios-close-outline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="1em" height="1em" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M403.1 108.9c-81.2-81.2-212.9-81.2-294.2 0s-81.2 212.9 0 294.2c81.2 81.2 212.9 81.2 294.2 0s81.2-213 0-294.2zm-12.3 281.9c-74.3 74.3-195.3 74.3-269.6 0-74.3-74.3-74.3-195.3 0-269.6s195.3-74.3 269.6 0c74.4 74.3 74.4 195.3 0 269.6z" fill="#626262"/><path d="M340.2 160l-84.4 84.2-84-83.8-11.8 11.8 84 83.8-84 83.8 11.8 11.8 84-83.8 84.4 84.2 11.8-11.8-84.4-84.2 84.4-84.2z" fill="#626262"/></svg></button>
  </div>
  </div>
  `;

  taskContainer_new.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", markup);
}

taskContainer.addEventListener("click", event => {
  const target = event.target;

  const id = target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.key;

  if (target.classList.contains("ion-ios-checkmark-outline")) {
    toggleTodo(id);
  } else if (target.classList.contains("ion-ios-close-outline")) {
    deleteTodo(target);
  }
});

function clearInput() {
  taskItem.value = "";
}

function toggleTodo(key) {
  const index = todoList.findIndex(item => item.id === Number(key));
  todoList[index].isCompleted = !todoList[index].isCompleted;

  const item = document.querySelector(`[data-key="${key}"]`);

  if (todoList[index].isCompleted) {
    item.classList.add("completed");
    console.log("class added");
  } else {
    item.classList.remove("completed");
  }
  updateUI();
}

function deleteTodo(target) {
  const targetTaskId = target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.key;
  const index = todoList.findIndex(item => item.id === Number(targetTaskId));

  console.log("todoList[index]", todoList[index]);

  todoList.splice(todoList[index], 1);

  updateUI();
}

showAllTasksNav.addEventListener("click", displayAllTasks);
showCompletedTasksNav.addEventListener("click", displayCompletedTask);

function displayCompletedTask() {
  showAllTasksNav.classList.remove("active");
  showCompletedTasksNav.classList.add("active");

  todoList.filter(function(index, value) {
    return index.isCompleted;
  });
}

function displayAllTasks() {
  showCompletedTasksNav.classList.remove("active");
  showAllTasksNav.classList.add("active");

  updateUI();
}
```

```
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>To Do List</h1>
      <div class="input__area">
        <form class="form">
          <input class="task" type="text" placeholder="Enter Task" />
          <input class="add" type="submit" value="ADD" />
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="todo__container">
        <ul class="task__nav">
          <li class="task__nav-item all">All Tasks</li>
          <li class="task__nav-item finished">Completed Tasks</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="items"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #aaffa9, #11ffbd); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    color: #666;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
h1 {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    text-align: center;
}
button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    transition: transform .1s;
    cursor: none;
    outline: none;
}
button i {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 150%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.task__nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.task__nav-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    font-size: 80%;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.task__nav-item.active {
    /* color: #eb4034; */
    font-weight: bold;
}
.input__area {
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    width: 100%;
} 
.input__area form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
.todo__container {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
}
input {
    outline: none;
  }
input[type="text"] {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type="text"]::placeholder {
    color: #ccc;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #ec5757;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.todo__item {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.todo__item.completed p::after {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    content: "Finished!";
    color: #ec5757;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 70%;
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your script to a [mcve] and remove anything that is not directly related to the problem (and therefor absolutely necessary).

Comment: Have a look at my answer and the `CodeSandbox` link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First issue** is because you are not passing the index of the todo to be deleted in to `splice` function

Change `deleteTodo` function as shown below

```
function deleteTodo(target) {
  const targetTaskId = target.closest('.todo__item').dataset.key;
  const index = todoList.findIndex(item => item.id === Number(targetTaskId));

  todoList.splice(index, 1);

  updateUI();
}
```

**2nd issue** is because you are adding `completed` class on the container element of todo but immediately after that you are calling `updateUI` function which removes the `completed` class.

Change `toggleTodo` function as shown below

```
function toggleTodo(key) {
  const index = todoList.findIndex(item => item.id === Number(key));
  todoList[index].isCompleted = !todoList[index].isCompleted;

  updateUI();
}
```

when you call `updateUI` function, you need to pass whether current todo is marked as completed or not. If it is, `showItems` function should add the `completed` class

Your `updateUI` function should be changed as

```
function updateUI() {
  taskContainer_new.textContent = "";

  todoList.forEach(el => {
    showItems(el.id, el.task, el.isCompleted);
  });

  localStorage.setItem("todolist", JSON.stringify(todoList));
}
```

and `showItems` function as

```
function showItems(id, task, isCompleted) {
  const markup = `
  <div class="todo__item ${isCompleted ? 'completed' : ''}" data-key=${id}>
  <p>${task}</p>
  <div class="icons">
  <button class="item__complete--btn"><svg class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="1em" height="1em" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M340.1 177.3L215.3 303l-47.2-47.2-17.8 17.8 56 56c2.5 2.5 5.9 4.5 8.9 4.5s6.3-2 8.8-4.4l133.7-134.4-17.6-18z" fill="#626262"/><path d="M256 48C141.1 48 48 141.1 48 256s93.1 208 208 208 208-93.1 208-208S370.9 48 256 48zm0 398.7c-105.1 0-190.7-85.5-190.7-190.7 0-105.1 85.5-190.7 190.7-190.7 105.1 0 190.7 85.5 190.7 190.7 0 105.1-85.6 190.7-190.7 190.7z" fill="#626262"/></svg></button>
  <button class="item__delete--btn"><svg class="ion-ios-close-outline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="1em" height="1em" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M403.1 108.9c-81.2-81.2-212.9-81.2-294.2 0s-81.2 212.9 0 294.2c81.2 81.2 212.9 81.2 294.2 0s81.2-213 0-294.2zm-12.3 281.9c-74.3 74.3-195.3 74.3-269.6 0-74.3-74.3-74.3-195.3 0-269.6s195.3-74.3 269.6 0c74.4 74.3 74.4 195.3 0 269.6z" fill="#626262"/><path d="M340.2 160l-84.4 84.2-84-83.8-11.8 11.8 84 83.8-84 83.8 11.8 11.8 84-83.8 84.4 84.2 11.8-11.8-84.4-84.2 84.4-84.2z" fill="#626262"/></svg></button>
  </div>
  </div>
  `;

  taskContainer_new.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", markup);
}
```

Here's a [working demo](https://jsbin.com/yowuhoxira/edit?html,css,js,output) which unlike your code, also shows list of completed tasks and all tasks correctly

Comment: This make sense a lot! I shouldn't have implemented class toggle manipulation in toggleTodo function as it supposed to be just for toggling isCompleted value, not for manipulating UI. Thank you for your clear explanation! :D

Answer (score 1):

Splice expects an index as first parameter and second parameter represents number of items to be deleted

```
array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX)
```

Try changing todoList.splice(todoList[index], 1); to

```
todoList.splice(index, 1);
```

For your second problem you dont have to add or remove 'completed' class from classlist, you can handle this conditionally when you create html markup within showItems method

```
function showItems(id, task) {
  const completedClassName = todoList.find(e => element.id === id).isCompleted ? 'completed' : '';

   const markup = `
    <div class="todo__item ${completedClassName}" data-key=${id}>
      ... remaining markup
    </div>
  `;
  taskContainer_new.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", markup);
}
```

Comment: I changed it and now delete function works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, can you elaborate more on the second issue ?

Comment: Yes, in order to mark a task as finished I made toggleTodo function. This function does two things: 1. change item's value of 'isCompleted' to true 2. add 'completed' class to item's html (<div class="todo__item">). However if I click Check Button to make that function work, 1 works but 2 doesn't work. When I inspect html, some changes seem to happend on html but it dissapears right away.

Comment: Thank you for the second solution! I couldn't come up with a solution that I use variable for class name. One thing I couldn't understand is .length part. Can I ask what does that part mean?

Comment: Filter method would return an array with length 1 if only the id of the todo passed is marked as completed in the todo list.In that case  length property would have value 1 which is a truthy value.If the id is not marked as completed the filter method would return an empty array and in that case the length property will be having 0 as value which is considered falsy.

Comment: @ShijilNarayan actually, the way you're using the `filter` method will return an array with all items where the `isCompleted` property is set to `true`, so it's not really related to the actual item that you want to check, and therefore is wrong

Comment: I checked it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In the `deleteTodo` function, you could just use `Array.filter` method to remove an item from the `todoList` array:

```js
function deleteTodo(target) {
  const targetTaskId = target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.key;

  todoList = todoList.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id !== Number(targetTaskId);
  });

  updateUI();
}
```

As for your second problem, the reason why `completed` class gets "deleted" immediately is because your `showItems` function re-renders your todo items without taking into consideration the fact that some items should have `completed` added inside the `class` attribute:

```js
function showItems(id, task) {
  const { isCompleted = false } = todoList.find(function(element) {
    return element.id === id;
  });
  const markup = `
    <div class="todo__item ${isCompleted ? "completed" : ""}" data-key=${id}>
      <p>${task}</p>
      <div class="icons">
        <button class="item__complete--btn"><svg class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="1em" height="1em" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M340.1 177.3L215.3 303l-47.2-47.2-17.8 17.8 56 56c2.5 2.5 5.9 4.5 8.9 4.5s6.3-2 8.8-4.4l133.7-134.4-17.6-18z" fill="#626262"/><path d="M256 48C141.1 48 48 141.1 48 256s93.1 208 208 208 208-93.1 208-208S370.9 48 256 48zm0 398.7c-105.1 0-190.7-85.5-190.7-190.7 0-105.1 85.5-190.7 190.7-190.7 105.1 0 190.7 85.5 190.7 190.7 0 105.1-85.6 190.7-190.7 190.7z" fill="#626262"/></svg></button>
        <button class="item__delete--btn"><svg class="ion-ios-close-outline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="1em" height="1em" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M403.1 108.9c-81.2-81.2-212.9-81.2-294.2 0s-81.2 212.9 0 294.2c81.2 81.2 212.9 81.2 294.2 0s81.2-213 0-294.2zm-12.3 281.9c-74.3 74.3-195.3 74.3-269.6 0-74.3-74.3-74.3-195.3 0-269.6s195.3-74.3 269.6 0c74.4 74.3 74.4 195.3 0 269.6z" fill="#626262"/><path d="M340.2 160l-84.4 84.2-84-83.8-11.8 11.8 84 83.8-84 83.8 11.8 11.8 84-83.8 84.4 84.2 11.8-11.8-84.4-84.2 84.4-84.2z" fill="#626262"/></svg></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;
  taskContainer_new.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", markup);
}
```

Here's the working code:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-firefly-7vt1j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Wow that ternary operator part looks so cool! I would like to implement this code, but as being a beginner of JavaScript, that first object destructuring line is a little difficult to understand. Looks very advanced!

Comment: @kayak that's just a way of saying to default the `isCompleted` property to `false` if that property is missing from the object that was found.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much!